# Wordpress Web UI dosen't load in browser

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

When I deploy the docker compose configuration that I wrote the Phpmyadmin starts, but my the Wordpress web UI dosen't work.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db: 3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

networks:
  wordpress_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  wordpress_data:
  db_data:
```

When I run it, it returns this log.

```
[+] Running 3/0
 ✔ Container wordpress-db-1          Created                                                                       0.0s
 ✔ Container wordpress-wordpress-1   Created                                                                       0.0s
 ✔ Container wordpress-phpmyadmin-1  Created                                                                       0.0s
Attaching to db-1, phpmyadmin-1, wordpress-1
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:16+00:00 [Warn] [Entrypoint]: /sys/fs/cgroup/name=systemd:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 14:misc:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 13:rdma:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 12:pids:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 11:hugetlb:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 10:net_prio:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 9:perf_event:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 8:net_cls:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 7:freezer:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 6:devices:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 5:memory:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 4:blkio:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 3:cpuacct:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 2:cpu:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 1:cpuset:/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59
db-1          | 0::/docker/2317c1f0a5859c6d5f870b809a6d8e6fe16797c12d24fe81a27fc7ccb6308f59/memory.pressure not writable, functionality unavailable to MariaDB
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
phpmyadmin-1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin-1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin-1  | [Fri Mar 01 20:33:16.971271 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) PHP/8.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
phpmyadmin-1  | [Fri Mar 01 20:33:16.971299 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
wordpress-1   | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress-1   | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress-1   | [Fri Mar 01 20:33:17.068314 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) PHP/8.2.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
wordpress-1   | [Fri Mar 01 20:33:17.068343 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.3.2-MariaDB-1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 068a6819eb63bcb01fdfa037c9bf3bf63c33ee42 as process 1
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=47763
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 47763; transaction id 14
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240301 20:33:17
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db-1          | 2024-03-01 20:33:17 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
db-1          | Version: '11.3.2-MariaDB-1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

I'll be grateful, if you can help me to fix this problem. I'm new to docker and containerizing.

What I want is to deploy a test container for experimenting with Wordpress and ChatGPT API integration.

Comment: this line looks wrong  `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db: 3306` and should be `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db`

Comment: Yes, the `wordpress` service environment variables are set incorrectly. These should all be of the form `{VARIABLE}={VALUE}` (equals sign separator see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#use-the-environment-attribute)) and there should be no spaces i.e. `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306`.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Error establishing a database connection" is a clue: there's a problem connecting Wordpress to MariaDB. As mentioned in the comments, you need to properly specify `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST`.

Here's a stripped down version of the `Dockerfile`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
```

[image]